# How to add Item Status to order confirmation email Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates, order-email

Is there a way to add the Item status (Ordered/Backordered) to the order confirmation email?

I tried below code.

```
<td class="item-status">
    <?php if ($_item->getQtyBackordered()): ?>
        <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $_item->getQtyBackordered()*1 ?> Backordered.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

It displayed below value:

[image]

But it should be ordered and backordered.
https://prnt.sc/wr9jez

Answer (score 0):

**you can use both condition to validate the status**

```
<?php 
if ($_item->getQtyBackordered() || $_item->getQtyOrdered()): ?>
<?php $status =  $_item->getQtyBackordered() ? $_item->getQtyBackordered() : $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>

        <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $status*1 ?> Backordered.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It displayed backordered : <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $status*1 ?> Backordered.</p>

Comment: It should be : <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $status*1 ?></p>